# How does tableView init() hierarchy works?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am calling NewsFeedTableView with no args[image]

but in NewsFeedTableView I'm overriding init with arguments actually.

[image]
How does this work? How this overridden init is being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your `NewsFeedTableView` using an initializer without parameters. The designated initializer for `UIView` is this one:

```
init(frame: CGRect)
```

A designated initializer will always be called during initialization of any class inheriting from `UIView`. `init()` initializer of `UIView` will call it with `CGRect.zero` as parameter.

Now, looking at the documentation of [init(frame:style:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614886-init) initializer of `UITableView`:

> If you initialize the table view with the UIView method init(frame:), the UITableView.Style.plain style is used as a default.

So basically:
1. `NewsFeedTableView()` calls `NewsFeedTableView(frame: CGRect.zero)`
2. `NewsFeedTableView(frame: CGRect.zero)` calls `NewsFeedTableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain)`

That is why your overridden initializer is being called